# How can I show Vacancy records that are within a certain radius of my Account records?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql

a Salesforce newbie here.

I have a geocoded Account object, and a Vacancy object. When I click on any account record, I need to see all the vacancies that are within a 30mile radius of that particular account.

To achieve this, I am creating a Lightning Component, inside of which  I loop over all the vacancy records, calculate the distance, and spit out a list of Vacancy records whose distance is less that 30miles. My goal is to add this component to Account object from Lightning Page. So when I click on record X(in the Account object), I get the vacancies around record X. When I click on record Y(in the Account object), vacancies around record Y.

I have created an Apex Class, a lighting component and a controller. I run the code bellow in the class, and try to show the data in the component.

The problem is, how can I pass the account record dynamically when I open that component/view from that particular account record? So essentially, when I click on Account record A, my custom component needs to know this, so that I can query based on that.

```
 List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Geolocation__c FROM Account];
 List<Vacancy_c> vacancies = [SELECT Id, Name, Geolocation_c FROM Vacancy__c];
 
 for(Account acc : accounts) {
     if(acc.Geolocation__c!=null) {
         Decimal lat = acc.Geolocation__c.getLatitude();
         Decimal longi = acc.Geolocation__c.getLongitude();
         Location acc_location = Location.newInstance(lat, longi);
             
         for(Vacancy__c vac : vacancies) {
             Decimal v_lat = vac.Geolocation__c.getLatitude();
             Decimal v_longi = vac.Geolocation__c.getLongitude();
             Location vac_location = Location.newInstance(v_lat, v_longi);           
             Double dist = Location.getDistance(acc_location, vac_location, 'mi');
             if(dist<=10) {
                 System.debug(vac);
             }
 
         }
     }
 }
```

This is what I currently have. I apologize if the formatting is bad.

I don’t know if there is any easier way to achieve this. If so, please let me know. I would highly appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: What is a 'Custom Component'? Where is this code running? What are you clicking on that changes the account? Please edit your question to provide more context as to what you actually have.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for stopping by.  I apologize for not clearing these earlier. I am quite new to Salesforce so please pardon my  lack of concepts.

Comment: I have edited my question as best as I could. But to summarize, 'Custom Component' is a lightning component. This code is running in an Apex Class at the moment. I am not, but wish to click on each Account records to see their details, and within that, view the list of surrounding Vacancies.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the account record dynamically to your Lightning component, you can use a Lightning component attribute that accepts the ID of the selected account record as a parameter. Here's an example of how you can modify your Apex code and Lightning component to achieve this:

**1. Apex Class:**

```
public class VacancyController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Vacancy__c> getVacanciesWithinRadius(String accountId) {
        List<Vacancy__c> vacancies = [SELECT Id, Name, Geolocation_c FROM Vacancy__c WHERE DISTANCE(Geolocation_c, GEOLOCATION(:accountId), 'mi') <= 30];
        return vacancies;
    }
}
```

Note that the SOQL query uses the DISTANCE function to calculate the distance between the vacancy record and the account record specified by the `accountId` parameter. This ensures that only vacancies within the 30-mile radius are returned.

**2. Lightning Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="VacancyController">
    <aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="vacancies" type="Vacancy__c[]" />
 
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
 
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.vacancies}" var="vacancy">
        <!-- display vacancy record data -->
    </aura:iteration>
</aura: component>
```

The `accountId` attribute accepts the ID of the selected account record. The vacancies attribute is used to store the list of vacancies that are within the 30-mile radius.

**3. Lightning Component Controller:**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var accountId = component.get("v.accountId");
        var action = component.get("c.getVacanciesWithinRadius");
        action.setParams({ accountId : accountId });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.vacancies", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

The `doInit` function is called when the component is initialized. It calls the `getVacanciesWithinRadius` Apex method and passes the `accountId` attribute as a parameter. The result is stored in the `vacancies` attribute.

To pass the account record ID dynamically, you can add the component to the Account record page and use a Quick Action or a button to open the component with the selected account record ID. You can then pass this ID to the component using the `accountId` attribute. For example, you can use the `force:navigateToComponent` event to navigate to the component and pass the account record ID as a parameter:

```
({
    navigateToComponent: function(component, event, helper) {
        var accountId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef: "c:VacancyList",
            componentAttributes: {
                accountId: accountId
            }
        });
        evt.fire();
    }
})
```

This code assumes that the component is named `VacancyList` and that the `recordId` attribute contains the ID of the selected account record. You can add this code to a Quick Action or a button on the Account record page. When the user clicks on the Quick Action or the button, the component is opened with the vacancies that are within the 30-mile radius of the selected account record.